# Integrate AutoMapper in my Unit Test doesn't work

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, automapper

My problem is that I am trying to add AutoMapper in my unit test, but I have one method that doesn't pass. I've tried to add to configure AutoMapper in the constructor, but it's still not working. I am not a pro in unit test, so can someone help me with this please.

```
public AssetControllerTest() 
{
    _loggerMock = new Mock<ILogger<AssetController>>();
    _sqlService = new Mock<ISqlService>();

    //_mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();

    if (_mapper == null)
    {
        var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
            {
                mc.AddProfile(new AssetProfile());
            });
        IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
        _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
    }
}
```

[This the test method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipL1r.png)

[This one is the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8VOH.png)

Comment: Why do you want to mock your mapping ?

Comment: It's indeed a good question... but since my test was not passing when I added the automapper to the controller, I thought that I should mock the mapping...